# Errors displayed during core upgrade

Tags: upgrading

When I am updating Drupal core, and uploading files via FTP, how can I prevent mydomain.com/install.php trying to load and displaying WSOD errors like "Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required..."?

I'd like to display a static page with a BRB message instead.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Why would you want to do such a thing? If you are getting the error, then probably there is something to fix, not to hide.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the error comes because the upload is in progress and files are missing, not because there is anything actually wrong.

Comment: Upload the files, and then update Drupal by going to mydomain.com/update.php. Why are you trying to do two things at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your entire Drupal root somewhere else, and put something else in its place (with a "Be Right Back"-message) while the upgrade goes on.

For instance, if your Drupal root is `/var/www/html`, prepare a directory named `/var/www/brb` and put a static `index.html`-file in it with your BRB message.

Then execute the following pair of commands:

```
mv /var/www/html /var/www/pending_upgrade
mv /var/www/brb /var/www/html
```

Now, make sure that your ftp job puts the files in below `/var/www/pending_upgrade`.

When done, restore your site with the following pair of commands:

```
mv /var/www/html /var/www/brb
mv /var/www/pending_upgrade /var/www/html
```

The above assumes that you have CLI access.  If you don't, most ftp tools have built-in commands to move directories around.

Comment: The OP is talking about mydomain.com/install.php. How does moving the files into a different directory avoid the OP gets WSODs?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, because when `settings.php` is missing or unreadable, or the DB is missing, Drupal redirects *any* attempts to access the site to `install.php`.  By making Drupal inaccessible for page requests (by moving it somewhere else), this redirection don't happen.

Comment: So, is the user saying that he is uploading the new files to the server, and users accessing the site get a WSOD? (I guess the question is not clear, to me.) I have never overridden the settings.php file to avoid problems with remembering the right credentials. Is there any good reason to update that too?

Comment: Thanks, Free Radical. That is exactly the issue. @kiamlaluno, I am sorry if my question is vague.